# symfony form label from required widget with stars

Tags: forms, symfony1, label, required

I'm searching the best way to output a label of a widget with a star (*) if this widget is required. It should be automatic.

I didn't find any way to do it :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to [use a custom form formatter](http://dark-it.blogspot.com/2009/01/symfony-mark-fields-as-required.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could always look at `setLabel` in the form clas:

`$this->widgetSchema->setLabel('YOUR_WIDGET', 'NAME <em>*</em>');`

This will show the widget: `NAME *` which you can then style in CSS

Comment: I don't want to set it for all my forms and widget

Answer (score 0):

With Symfony2 I'm going to use this simple CSS trick

```
.required:after {
    content: "*";
}
```

Found [here](https://coderwall.com/p/15q88g/symfony2-forms-easiest-way-to-add-an-to-required-field-labels)